# remove content of homepage

Tags: local.xml

I'm trying to remove a static block from homepage, using local.xml.

Tried:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.flexslider.js</name></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="banners-homepage"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

But the page still shows the static block (banners-homepage, which war created as static cms block).

What is my mistake? Cache is disabled.

---

Following is the cms page code relative to that block:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="5"}}</p>
```

Comment: Could you post how the block is inserted ? Also try without the `reference` tag

Comment: Thanks for having a look, I updated the original question adding the code in the cms page that calls the banner I want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Simply go to the CMS -> widgets in Magento Admin Panel and remove the widget . Or you can check in static block search for id 5 and diable it

Comment: thanks, but the thing is that I'll use the same homepage in both themes, mobile and regular one. I need to disable it only in mobile one.

Comment: get the id of your home page according to that remove or inactive that particular code.

Comment: that is what I'm trying to do, unfortunately it seems my query is either badly formed or that there's something I'm missing, as the elemnt is still shown. Any specific pointer on how to do it?

Comment: tell me one thing are you using multiple stores ?

Comment: no, single store

Comment: i have a better solution why don't you hide that section when your theme is in mobile resolution you can achieve it using media query